# Losing variable value assigned in iCheck callback in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, icheck

I'm new at this so be kind.

I've got these 2 functions inside the same component.ts

First one:

```
addCost() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
                    (<any>$('input')).iCheck({
                        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
                        radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-grey'
                    });
                    $('#not2bpaid').on('ifChecked', () => {
                        this.not2bpaid_tosend = "N";
                    });
}
```

This variable assignment in 'ifChecked' callback works, I've made sure of that.

And then I have another function which is called on click event in html which uses the variable not2bpaid_tosend.

addCost() is called BEFORE the function at click event, but by then not2bpaid_tosend has lost its value.

I've also tried passing not2bpaid_tosend as a parameter to the 2nd function upon triggering it from html. Same result. Variable is empty by then.
And I'm not touching that variable at any other time between those 2 functions.

Not sure what's going on here or how to solve it. Probably something simple that I overlooked since, as I said, I'm new at this angular stuff.

Any help would be appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use arrow function while passing function an argument to the ready function of jquery to keep the context of component class intact.

```
addCost() {
  $(document).ready(() => {
    (<any>$('input')).iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
      radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-grey'
    });
    $('#not2bpaid').on('ifChecked', () => {
      this.not2bpaid_tosend = "N";
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Yup. That was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Cabman If the answer suits you can you please approve it. Thanks.